# Problem with gzip compressing utf-8 encoded php page. HELP!

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, compression, gzip

i use this at top of my php page:

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
else
    ob_start();
```

when page is save with ANSI encoding page was compressed. but when i change page encoding to utf-8 compression was faild. please help!!!

i test compression on www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By guess is that you are including a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) in your PHP source file when you save in UTF-8 and that's corrupting the compressed stream. Make sure you save in the file in UTF-8 **without BOM**.

Comment: perfect guess!! the problem was BOM character at beginning. thanks artefacto